# obtaining multiple changes at once using vimdiff

Tags: vimdiff

I'm using vimdiff to merge a changes from another group's file into our file.
Not all changes should be accepted, so I have to do it manually.
However, I was wondering if there is a way to tell vimdiff to accept several changes at once.
i.e. instead of accepting only the next change, I want to able to accept the next 10 changes at once.
Right now I'm using "]c" to jump to the next change and "do" to accept that change.
The file is 250000 lines and I'm only at line 5000 ...

Sincerely,
Hagai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish exactly what you want with macros, in a nutshell:

1. **In normal mode, press 'q' and a random letter, lets say 'f':** This will start recording a macro in the register 'f'.
2. **Perform the actions you want to repeat:** In this case ']c' and 'do'.
3. **Stop recording the macro:** Just press 'q' again.

Now you can use it by typing **'@f'** in normal mode and it will replay the actions recorded in the macro 'f'. From there you have several options:

- If you type **'@@'** vim will replay the last macro. Hint: if you just keep the combination pressed in the keyboard it will do it line by line very fast.
- If you type **'1000@f'** vim will replay the last macro 1000 times, which is pretty much what you are looking for.
- If you want to save some typing, you can record a new macro i.e. 'g' performing '1000@f', that way '@g' will call '1000@f', although if you use '@@' after '@g' it will do it line by line.

There is a nice tutorial here:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/vi-and-vim-macro-tutorial-how-to-record-and-play/

Comment: @user2307618 I'm sure you don't need this anymore, but I post the solution just for the record